# Customized Replacing in R Studio

Tags: r, replace

I have a homework to analyze data of [Bloomberg Billionaires Index](https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/) in R Studio, but I am facing a problem with the periods.. There are three forms of values:

1. 185B (No periods)
2. 18.5B (one digit after the period)
3. 1.85B (two digits after the period)

I want to delete the dots and add nine zeros in place of the billion symbol (B) but that means the three values will be the same.
Is there a way to add:

- Nine zeros for the first formula (where there are no points)
- Eight zeros for the second formula (where there is one digit after
  the period)
- Seven zeros for the third formula (where there are two digits after
  the period)

Thank you!!

Comment: How about removing the B and multiplying with 10^9?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!
in the next column, there are B, M and K. Is there a way to apply a different multiply function for each of them?
I mean the "$ Last change" column in this set: https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/ 
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Finally I solved it with ifelse:
     df$v = ifelse(grepl("B", df$x) ,df$y*10^9,
     ifelse(grepl("M", df$x), df$y*10^6,
     df$y*10^3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c('185B', '18.5B', '1.85B')
as.numeric(sub('B', '', x, fixed = TRUE)) * 10^9
```

If use of packages are allowed you can use `readr::parse_number` to get the number directly.

```
readr::parse_number(x) * 10^9
```

Comment: Thank you! But there are 500 values is the column (185 is just an example). What should I write to include them all?

Comment: Instead of `x` you have to pass the column value. If your dataframe is called `df` and column is called `col` you can replace `x` with `df$col`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks! What if the column contains B, M and K. Is there a way to apply different multiply function for each of them. I mean the "$ Last change" column in this set: https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/ 
Thank you!

Comment: You can use `ifelse` to do that. If you have trouble implementing ask that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally solved it with ifelse: : df$v = ifelse(grepl("B", df$x) ,df$y*10^9, ifelse(grepl("M", df$x), df$y*10^6, df$y*10^3))

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_remove(x, 'B')) * 10 ^9
#[1] 1.85e+11 1.85e+10 1.85e+09
```

#### data

```
x <- c('185B', '18.5B', '1.85B')
```